# Iterating over form to submit dynamic data to flask via jQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a web app with flask that has rows of data obtained from API calls. Currently I have a column called 'Ticket Number' that contains a set of numbers. My desired functionality is for the user to click on a number and have a modal present more specific information (via a separate python API call). I'm using AJAX to send the data to my flask app to prevent a page refresh on click. The only problem is that no matter which button I click, it thinks I am clicking the first button listed and gives me the results for the first number. Below I've posted the Python, jQuery, and html. Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thanks for your time.

jQuery:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ticket',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Flask:

```
@app.route('/ticket', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def ticket_drill():

    ticket_number = request.form['ticketNumber']

    header = {
        'authorization': "super_secret_key",
        'content-type': "application/json",
        'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }
    s = requests.get("https://my_site/v4_6_release/apis/3.0/service/tickets/" + 
    str(ticket_number), headers=header)
    ticket_details = json.loads(s.text)
    ticket_id = ticket_details['id']

    return json.dumps({'status':'OK','Ticket Number:':ticket_id});
```

HTML:

```
{% for ticket_number in service_board %}
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form class="form-signin" action="/serviceboard" method="post" role="form">
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button">{{ticket_number}}
                                <input type="hidden" name="ticketNumber" value="{{ticket_number}}" />
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>    
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give your button an id and call that with the jquery like so:

```
$().ready(function(){
$('button#ticketNumberButton').on('click',function() {
    var ticketNumberVar = $(this).parent().find(' form ').find('#ticketNumber');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ticket',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            obj = JSON.parse(response);
            ticketNumberVar.val(obj.Ticket_Number);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

});

Maybe this is just me, but I would get rid of the space and ";" in your view as well.

```
return json.dumps({'status':'OK','Ticket_Number:':ticket_id})
```

HTML:

```
{% for ticket_number in service_board %}
        <tr>
                <td>
                    <form class="form-signin" action="/serviceboard" method="post" role="form">
                        <input type="hidden" id="ticketNumber" name="ticketNumber" value="{{ticket_number}}" />

                    </form>
                    <button id="ticketNumberButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button">{{ticket_number}}</button>

                </td>    
</tr>
```

{% endfor %}

Hopefully that helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still just gives me the info for the first result no matter which number I click.

Comment: I'll need more information than that or code to help you. Maybe play around with using :first or :last in jquery and use console.log to find out where you are in the DOM.

Comment: What I ended up doing was removing the form from the for loop and sticking it at the bottom of the page which let me inject the button's value into the input's value when it was clicked via a simple js function. I think the python was the problem, it was looking for the first thing with the name 'ticketNumber', so it never made it past the first button. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh I understand the problem. So basically there was more than one id/name with ticketNumber or ticketNumberButton which caused the error. Moving it out of the loop only created one instance, solving the issue. I've often used loop.index to name specific id's in loops and then utilized a script call to a function to get the results needed. Anyway, glad you solved the issue!